# Determine the return type of dynamic type

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have chosen to create an anonymous type for temporary projection in a LINQ Join query. I am using ExpressionTrees, to build the query at runtime. I donot know if the following code would help me with creating a temporary projected sequence.

Here is the code that does the temporary Projection:

```
private Expression<Func<EntityObject, EntityObject,dynamic>> TempProjectionExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return (o, p) => new
            {
                o = o,
                p = p
            };
        }
    }
```

My Join Query using Expression Trees is given below.

```
    public IQueryable<dynamic> GetQueryExpressionresults3<T, U, V>(IQueryable<T> aEntityCollection1, IQueryable<U> aEntityCollection2, Type[] _TypeArguments ,V _anonymousType, string aPropertyName)
        where T : EntityObject
        where U : EntityObject
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), "o");
        ParameterExpression pe1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        //This should be populated from UI
        Expression me = Expression.Property(pe1, typeof(T).GetProperty(aPropertyName));
        //This should be populated from UI
        Expression me1 = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(U).GetProperty(aPropertyName));

        LambdaExpression le = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(me, new ParameterExpression[] { pe1 });
        LambdaExpression le1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, int>>(me1, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });

        _TypeArguments = new Type[] { aEntityCollection1 .ElementType, aEntityCollection2.ElementType, le.Body.Type, typeof(MovieCollections)};
        //_TypeArguments = _TypeArguments.Concat(new Type[] { le.Body.Type, typeof(object) }).ToArray();

        MethodCallExpression JoinCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Join", _TypeArguments, aEntityCollection1.Expression, aEntityCollection2.Expression
            , le, le1, TempProjectionExpression);

        var oResult = aEntityCollection1.Provider.CreateQuery(JoinCallExpression) as IQueryable<dynamic>;

        return oResult;
    }
```

Now the question is, i would like to determine the return type of the TempProjectionExpression, i.e. typeof(dynamic). Is this possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

`typeof(dynamic)` can't do any better than `System.Object` (which the compiler won't even try to do) which isn't a very interesting result.

You can use `returnedResult.GetType()`, though, to get its runtime type.

Since `dynamic` puts off type resolution to runtime, there's no way to tell what the return is before something is actually returned without doing type analysis on your expression tree worthy of the C# compiler itself.

Comment: typeof(dynamic) is giving a compile time error. I have tried with TempProjectionExpression.Body.Type to determine the return type of the dynamic type. It's doesn't give any compiler errors, but em not sure if it is correct.